# Finding Apps by Country of Origin - Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I am working on a project and I need to crawl the app-store and find apps that are developed in a specific country.

There is a [42matters.com API](https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/ios/apps/advanced-query-api) that has an option for 'publisher_geo_context' but I am not sure how accurate is that, and more importantly, it does not have the countries I need to search for.

Using this and other APIs (or even manually on Play Store), one does find the name of the publisher, and the website etc, but cannot find which country the developer is from. (Without using some other info, such as going to their facebook page and figuring it out, etc.) The 'Physical address' is not reliable since it is only required for apps that have in-app purchases or are paid AFAIK.

**How can I find which country an app publisher/developer is from? Is there a way to easily generate a list of apps?**

I cannot rely on domain names of publisher's websites e.g. I cannot pull a list of apps for developers with websites ending in a '.it' for apps from Italy, for example.

Comment: I'm an app developer with apps published on the Play Store. Google tells me the physical address is required, but it doesn't have to be my address. Other than that, there's no other public information for the country of origin. I have to set up a billing address, but that's not publicly available. I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

@DSM I have had a similar situation, then I came across [www.fnd.io](https://www.fnd.io)

I am not sure about Google PlayStore but it is an alternate to Apple Store. It lets you view apps from any specific country by click the flag icon in the top-left of the navigation. You can enter the name of the country and it will list the apps from that specific country.

Good luck,
Martin

Comment: I didn't want to look at the 'charts' in a country i.e. which apps are popular in a specific country, but which apps are developed in a specific country.